# How can I show the regions between the grid lines in a RadialAxisPlot in different colours?

Tags: plotting, graphics

With the following:

```
RadialAxisPlot[{3, 8, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c"}]
```

I obtain the expected output:

[image: Radial axis plot]

But I would like the regions between the concentric circles to have different colours. I know there is a function called `RadialGradientFilling`, but the following does not work:

```
Graphics[
    {
        RadialGradientFilling[{2, 6, 10} -> {Green, Purple, Red}],
        RadialAxisPlot[{3, 8, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c"}]
    }
]
```

Am I overlooking a simple option somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the radial ticks suggest that the circle radii range from 0 to 10, they actually range from 0 to 1. So we can add as `Prolog` or `Epilog` a disk with unit radius styled using `RadialGradientFilling`. Adding opacity to the gradient filling makes the main plot elements more visible:

```
RadialAxisPlot[{3, 8, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c"}, 
 Prolog -> {RadialGradientFilling[{.2, .6, 1.} -> 
   (Append[.3] /@ {Green, Purple, Red})], Disk[]}]
```

[image]

A variation using annuli each with its own gradient filling:

```
RadialAxisPlot[{3, 8, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c"}, 
 Prolog -> 
   MapThread[{RadialGradientFilling[Append[.3] /@ {White, #2}], Annulus[{0, 0}, #]} &, 
   {Partition[{0.001, .2, .6, 1}, 2, 1], {Green, Purple, Red}}]]
```

[image]

Or use annuli with different colors without gradient filling:

```
RadialAxisPlot[{3, 8, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c"}, 
 Prolog ->  MapThread[{Opacity[.25, #2], Annulus[{0, 0}, #]} &, 
   {Partition[{0.001, .2, .6, 1}, 2, 1], {Green, Purple, Red}}]]
```

[image]

If the gridlines are linear (as the option  `GridLines -> "Polygon"` will produce) the directives `RadialGradientFilling` and `LinearGradientFilling` do not give nice pictures:

```
Row[RadialAxisPlot[{3, 8, 5}, ImageSize -> 300, 
     AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c"},  GridLines -> "Polygon", 
     Prolog -> {RadialGradientFilling[{.2, .6, 1.} -> 
        (Append[.3] /@ {Green, Purple, Red})], #}] & /@ 
  {Disk[], Polygon[CirclePoints[{1, Pi/2}, 3]]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

The following function `lGFPolygon` produces a regular polygon with linear-radial gradient filling:

```
ClearAll[lGFPolygon]
lGFPolygon[n_][colors_, weights_ : Automatic, opacity_ : .3] := 
 Module[{cp = Most @ Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, n], 
   c = If[Head[colors] === String, colors, 
       (weights /. Automatic -> Most[Subdivide[Length@colors]]) -> 
         (Append[opacity] /@ colors)]}, 
  tri = {LinearGradientFilling[c, Top], Polygon @ Prepend[{0, 0}]@
      Transpose[Through[{Cos, Sin} @ Take[Pi/2 - Pi/n + cp, 2]]]}; 
  Table[Rotate[tri, a, {0, 0}], {a, Pi/n + cp}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
RadialAxisPlot[{3, 8, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c"}, 
 GridLines -> "Polygon", 
 Prolog -> { lGFPolygon[3][{Green, Purple, Red}, {.2, .6, 1}, .5]}]
```

[image]

```
RadialAxisPlot[{3, 8, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c"}, 
 GridLines -> "Polygon", 
 Prolog -> { lGFPolygon[3]["SunsetColors"]}]
```

[image]

```
data = {3, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5};
RadialAxisPlot[data, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}, 
 GridLines -> "Polygon", 
 Prolog -> {lGFPolygon[Length@data][{Green, Purple, Red}, {.2, .6, 1}, .5]}]
```

[image]

**Update:**  An alternative way to get linear-radial filling for polygon grid lines is to use `DensityPlot` of distance from the boundary of a regular polygon:

```
ClearAll[dP]
dP[n_, colors_, vals_ : Automatic, opacity_ : .5] := 
 Module[{rp = RegularPolygon[{1, Pi/2}, n], rd}, 
  rd = RegionDistance[RegionBoundary @ rp]; 
  DensityPlot[rd[{x, y}], {x, y} ∈ rp,  
  Exclusions -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> If[Head[colors] === String, colors, 
     Blend[Thread[{1 - (vals /. Automatic -> Rest[Subdivide[Length@colors]]), 
         Append[opacity] /@ colors}], #] &],  
   PlotPoints -> 100]]
```

**Examples:**

```
RadialAxisPlot[{1, 3, 8, 4, 2, 1, 4}, GridLines -> "Polygon", 
 AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"},
 LabelStyle -> 16,
 TicksStyle -> Directive[FontColor -> Darker @ Gray, White],
 GridLinesStyle -> White,
 AxesStyle -> White, Filling -> None,
 Prolog -> dP[7, {Green, Purple, Red}, {0, .6, 1}][[1]]]
```

[image]

Use `Prolog -> dP[Length @ data ,"SunsetColors"][[1]]` to get

[image]

Use `Prolog -> (dP[Length @ data, "Rainbow"][[1]]/. c_?ColorQ :> Opacity[.3, c])` to get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
RadialAxisPlot[{3, 8, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c"}, 
 Prolog -> {RadialGradientFilling[{.2, .6, 1} -> {Green, Purple, 
      Red}, {1/2, 1/2}], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}]
```

[image]